How to update same table in two CTEs in postgresql
So it seems requests of a CTE update cannot be used in the WHERE clause of another CTE on the same table?
Basically I have a situation like this
WITH update_expiry AS (
    UPDATE products
    SET expiry = COALESCE($1, expiry)
    WHERE id = '$1'
    RETURNING *
),
update_fields AS (
    UPDATE products
    SET name = COALESCE(NULL, name)
    -- other fields ---  
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true from update_expiry WHERE expiry < now())
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT id from update_fields;

And for some strange reason WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true from update_expiry WHERE expiry < now()) always return false, even though I can confirm that update_expiry does contain rows if I do
WITH update_expiry AS (
    UPDATE products
    SET expiry = COALESCE($1, expiry)
    WHERE id = '$1'
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT true from update_expiry WHERE expiry < now();

So the first CTE actually contains rows, but if I try to use it in the WHERE clause in the second CTE it does not work.
I also confirm the issue is the CTE because if I explicit set the value in the WHERE clause to TRUE as below it works
WITH update_expiry AS (
    UPDATE products
    SET expiry = COALESCE($1, expiry)
    WHERE id = '$1'
    RETURNING *
),
update_fields AS (
    UPDATE products
    SET name = COALESCE(NULL, name)
    -- other fields ---  
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true)
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT id from update_fields;

What am I doing wrong? How do I use the result in the first CTE in the WHERE clause in the second CTE.
UPDATE:
Playing around with this more, it seems if there are two CTEs that updates the same table, the first CTE is basically ignored?
For example:
WITH update_expiry AS (
    UPDATE products
    SET expiry = COALESCE($1, expiry)
    WHERE id = '$1'
    RETURNING *
),
update_fields AS (
    UPDATE products
    SET name = COALESCE(NULL, name)
    WHERE id = '$1'
    RETURNING *
)
...

Looks like update_expiry is never executed but update_fields is. Is this indeed the behavior?

As the docs SELECT explain: The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified.  Read DATA MODIFYING CTEs  for your options.

Within a query, all reads from a table will return the rows as they were at the time the query started (consistent reads). Once a row has been modified in a query, that same row cannot be modified again (nor can its new value be accessed other than through the results of the RETURNING clause). Please review [mre]. Are id and expiry of the same type? If not, then COALESCE($1, expiry) doesn't make sense. COALESCE(NULL, name) is equivalent to just name. Consider using a single UPDATE: from what was presented, it should be a simple exercise.
